# Apple screen gets scrambled randomly

Tags: macos, safari, macbook-pro

Recently I upgraded to Lion, since doing this upgrade I am now getting a bug with Safari where the browser window "scrambles". By this, I mean that the entire window breaks up into rectangular blocks say .8cm x 1 - 2cm of different colours etc. Each of these blocks can be a solid or mixture of colours.

I have noticed this happen with the desktop once, and the Finder as well so I'm pretty sure its not just Safari-related, although it happens in Safari ~99% of the time. If I am watching something like YouTube, the video remains ok but all other page content gets scrambled.

To add some background to this I have had this MacBook for 4+ years now and never had any issues like this until I changed to Lion from Snow Leopard.

I was wondering if anyone else has had this issue or heard of it and knows how it can be fixed?

Comment: Safari has had some bugs where the screen gets scrambled for quite some time. Especially in the "Show Top Sites" view when many files are requested from the web render process now that Safari has a different architecture. Are you able to post a picture of this distortion - I rarely get this now that I have 8G of RAM on my primary mac. My experience is it happens more when the system is under memory pressure.

Comment: Is the scrambling restricted to a window or does it occur across the whole screen?

Comment: I will try screenshot it next time it happens, it is restricted to the safari window usually, though i did get it in a finder window and on desktop one time.  I doubt its a RAM issue though as Im running 4Gb in the macbook and Im usually only browsing the web when it appears

Comment: For the moment, the primary suspects are a graphic driver (maybe an installation error) or a graphic card failure/incompatibility. Let's see how your screenshots look like.